# resultSet.getObject(1); where does the cast occur?

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I would like to know when using the ResultSet instance method: `getObject(int columnNumber);` how come that it gets automatically cast to the column type? It's something implicitly done by the ResultSet Object?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Be extremely wary when you use ResultSet.getObject(), you can get different behavior with different drivers (e.g. for a SMALLINT column, some drivers return a java.lang.Short, while others may return a java.lang.Integer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not get cast to the column type, it is already that type when stored in the `ResultSet`. This method will returns an `Object` or *any object whose class extends `Object`* which is, obviously **any** class.

Answer (score 2):

getObject() returns an object of the Java type associated with the column type. So if it's a VARCHAR, you'll get a `String` (which extends Object). If it's a BIT, you'll get a Boolean (which extends Object), etc. Everything extends Object in Java.

That's what the method does and [is documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject%28int%29) to do:

> This method will return the value of the given column as a Java object. The type of the Java object will be the default Java object type corresponding to the column's SQL type, following the mapping for built-in types specified in the JDBC specification. If the value is an SQL NULL, the driver returns a Java null.

Answer (score 1):

> Gets the value of the designated column in the current row of this
>   ResultSet object as an Object in the Java programming language
>
> This method will return the value of the given column as a Java
>   object. The type of the Java object will be the default Java object
>   type corresponding to the column's SQL type, following the mapping for
>   built-in types specified in the JDBC specification. If the value is an
>   SQL NULL, the driver returns a Java null

return type is Object.

All classes in java are subclass of Object.

[**JAVA DOCS**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject%28int%29)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a different [`getObject()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject%28java.lang.String,java.lang.Class%29) method where you can indicate what type you are expecting:

```
MyClass myObject = getObject(columnIndex, MyClass.class)
```